# Why Representation of Clifford algebra are constant for an orthonormal frame?

Tags: spin-geometry, clifford-algebras

Let $e_\alpha$ be a basis of the tangent bundle $TM$ and $ \rho: T_x M \rightarrow \operatorname{End}\left( W\right)$ a representation of a Clifford algebra.

In this text [Field theory from a bundle point of view](https://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/lectures.pdf)
 by Laurent Claessens he claims at page 122 that if the frame $e_\alpha$ are orthonormal everywhere, then we have the matricial equality
$$
\rho\left(\left(e_\alpha\right)_x\right)_{i j}=\rho\left(v_\alpha\right)_{i j}
$$
where  $v_\alpha$ is a basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Why this claim is true?

Comment: I presume that the $ij$ components are with respect to some local trivialization of $W$. If $W$ has no global trivialization, a global version of that equality is a priori impossible. But given a local trivialization, if the Clifford generators are not constant, the trivialization can be adjusted to make them constant.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine where can I find the proof of that?

Comment: Roughly speaking, anything local you do with an orthonormal frame which doesn't involve differentiating can't feel curvature, so looks identical to the same calculation in Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451526/?noredirect=1#comment1167468_451526), the claim can only hold with respect to a particular local trivialization of $W$. Suppose you picked such a trivialization, then you can define a representation $\rho$, which is constant with respect to it. Any other representation $\rho'$ will then differ from $\rho$ by an automorphism of $\operatorname{End}(W)$. But the fibers of $\operatorname{End}(W)$ are just matrix algebras, and by the [Skolem-Nöther theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) any such automorphism is inner, i.e., induced by a transformation of the fiber of $W$. So $\rho$ and $\rho'$ will differ by a change of trivialization of $W$. I invite you consider the exercise of showing that the change of trivialization is continuous/smooth when $\rho'$ is.